# Holo effects to programmatically generated textviews?

Tags: android, textview, android-holo-everywhere

I'm generating **TextViews** on **LinearLayout** programmatically  and I want to display the programmatically generated TextViews with **Holo effects** while on touch on the LinearLayout

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)  {
  LinearLayout linLayout= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.sideIndex);
  TextView tv = new TextView(this);
  tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
// tmpTV.setTypeface(font);
  tv.setText(tmpLetter);
  tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
  tv.setTextSize(11); 
  tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.holo_green_light));

 LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,2);

 tv.setLayoutParams(params);

 linLayout.addView(tv);
}
```

I'm able to view the Holo TextViews with this

> tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.holo_green_light));

But I want to view the holo effect on TextView after ontouch on the LinearLayout.

below code working fine for a single instance of programmatically  generated TextView but I need to display more than one number of text view in Holo after user touch the LinearLayout!

```
  linLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
           tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.holo_blue_bright));
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Isn't the theme declaration for the activity just enough? Aren't all the widgets inheriting all the theme attributes?

Comment: @RobertEstivill  updated the question! I have problem with pragmatically generated stuff!  theme declaration I have done!..but no effect on TextView!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should set the holo background selector, so your textview responds to the select/pressed/onfocus states. Don't know exactly where the selector is in the holo theme or how it's named, but that should be it.